# some exercises to realize the very basic concepts of the sheaves and presheaves

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, sheaf-theory

I am reading my notes on sheaves and presheaves, that I wrote many years ago. But I can not get a deep connection to the subject, and when I read them, after some hours I will forget them.

I think the solution is to solve a few exercises (like 10-15 exercises to 20-30 exercises) on the subject. I am not looking for hard problems or problems for competitions. I am looking for a few informative, instructive problems on the subject. I should emphasize that I am very beginner to the subject, and I just want to deal with:

- The definition of Sheaves and presheaves
- Stalks
- Morphism of sheaves
- Sheafification
- Some simple connection with category theory
- Some relations with the Picard group.

For instance, I am not looking for some problems concerning Cohomology, because I do not know cohomology yet.

---

Can anyone introduce a good reference to find some pedagogic problems on sheaves and presheaves? something like a chapter of a book, or a note or something else.

Comment: Some references i know are the third chapter of Wedhorn's "Manifolds, sheaves and cohomology", it has a lot of exercises that start from the basics. In chapter 8 there are some exercises concerning the Picard group. Another reference could be the second chapter of "Foundations of algebraic geometry" by Vakil; he develops the theory mainly through exercises

Comment: I've never heard the name of the first reference by "Wedhorn" that you've introduced. Thank you so much. Also, I didn't ever read the reference by "Vakil", but maybe it have a lot of exercises, because you said that "he develops the theory mainly through exercises". I am not looking for a bulky source of exercises. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I recommend Hartshorne Chapter II Section 1. It is a summary but the exercises are great and hits the first 5 of your bullet points in that one section.

Also, you should carry a few canonical examples in mind. One very important one is the sheaf of holomorphic functions on a complex domain. Here topics like stalks/germs are very explicit and classically covered by many complex analysis texts.